# React: "history" prop is not available in a private route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React 16, React-router-dom 4 and Mobx in my app.

I have this code for a private route:

```
export default (props) => {

    console.log('props from private',props)//Here i can see that the component doesn't contain the "history" prop.

    const Component = props.component;  

    const match = props.computedMatch
    if (isValidated()) {
        return (
            <div>
                <div><Component  {...props} match={match} /></div>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
    }

};
```

This is the routing setup:

```
export const history = createHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute  path="/" component={Chat} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

For some reason, the history prop just doesn't exist in the private route, therefore i'm unable to use the this.props.history.push function, to redirect programatically. The prop does get passed to a "normal" route though.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

wrap component with withRouter.

```
withRouter(component_name)
```